# how can i use owl carousel with symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, owl-carousel-2

I'm working on a symfony project and i need  include an owl carousel on it. I have add owl carousel with this command "yarn add owl.carousel jquery" and i see owl carousel plugin in the node_modules folder but now i don't know how i can use it. 
Could you help me please ?

I'm using webpack encore for compact all javascript and CSS files.

if you want te see, how owl carousel work go on this : https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So be sure to include the javascript and css of your Owl carrousel plugin in your page

(And you need Jquery for it)

```
<script src="/node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
```

Then do your carrousel :

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
</div>
```

And then call the plugin with javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
});
```

Comment: Thank for the help ! Yes i have import jquerry on my project. I try to include but in the web console i have 2 error: 
GEThttp://localhost:8000/node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:105 
GET http://localhost:8000/node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)